# Getting RequestId: <some_random_id> Process exited before completing request error in Lambda for Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

This is my code which was written in inside AWS Lambda function to build an alexa-skill. But I'm getting this error

> "RequestId: some_random_id Process exited before completing request
>   error".

Can anyone help me?

```
'use strict';
 const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
 const APP_ID = undefined;
 const SKILL_NAME = 'Space Facts';
 const GET_FACT_MESSAGE = "Here's your fact: ";
 const HELP_MESSAGE = 'You can say tell me a space fact, or, you can      say exit... What can I help you with?';
 const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
 const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';

 const handlers = {
     'LaunchRequest': function () {
         this.emit(':ask', 'Welcome to my world');
     },
     'Unhandled': function(){
       this.emit(':tell', "Sorry, I don\'t want to do");
     },
     'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
         const speechOutput = HELP_MESSAGE;
         const reprompt = HELP_REPROMPT;
         this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
         this.emit(':responseReady');
     },
     'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
         this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
         this.emit(':responseReady');
     },
     'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
         this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
         this.emit(':responseReady');
     },
 };

 exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
     const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
     alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
     alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
     alexa.execute();
 };
```

Comment: Which Intent did you call? You did change the `APP_ID` to your Skill's ID?

Comment: I didn't called any Intent. LaunchIntent itself not calling.